How to properly configure a Raid 6
Ubuntu Server 22.04.4 with KDE on top. I have 5 4TB platters connected and an SSD for the OS.  Below is the output of mdadm --detail.  It does show 4 devices with 1 removed. I added in the sde drive but it mounts as /run and does not show as "Linux Raid Member". I tried to remove sdf as it failed but it is still there and came back to life.

Here is output of mdadm --detail
sudo mdadm --query --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
Version : 1.2
Creation Time : Wed May  1 22:47:05 2024
Raid Level : raid6
Array Size : 7812855808 (7.28 TiB 8.00 TB)
Used Dev Size : 3906427904 (3.64 TiB 4.00 TB)
Raid Devices : 4
Total Devices : 3
Persistence : Superblock is persistent
 Intent Bitmap : Internal

   Update Time : Mon Oct 28 18:33:24 2024
         State : active, degraded 
Active Devices : 3

Working Devices : 3
Failed Devices : 0
Spare Devices : 0
        Layout : left-symmetric
    Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap
          Name : exodus:0  (local to host exodus)
          UUID : 84d87ff4:fd71dd56:b1a699c3:65f2657e
        Events : 542411

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8       49        0      active sync   /dev/sdd1
   1       8       33        1      active sync   /dev/sdc1
   5       8       64        2      active sync   /dev/sde
   -       0        0        3      removed

